# Extract single color from PDF using Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript

I need to extract the black from a Spot color PDF to a TIFF. I've used -`sDEVICE=tiffsep` which outputs all of the Spot colors but I only need the black. I tried to use `SeparationColorNames` and `Order` but I can't get it to work. For example:

```
-dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dBATCH -sDEVICE=tiffsep -r300x300 -c -sOutputFile=C:\Temp\Test.tif "<< /SeparationColorNames [/58600 /46351 /48253 /52813 /61121] /SeparationOrder [/58600] >> setpagedevice" C:\temp\Spot.pdf -c quit
```

This returns `/undefinedfilename in << /SeparationColorNames [/58600 /46351 /48253 /52813 /61121] /SeparationOrder [/58600] >> setpagedevice)`

I'm new to GS and this is not my domain so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use tiffsep and discard the plates you don't want. You can't control Ghostscript and prevent it writing the other plates.

Use the %s syntax for the filenames, that way you will get files like test.cyan.tif etc and you can easily pick out the black plate.